# What's wrong with the code in MSDN article "How to: Schedule Work on the User Interface (UI) Thread"?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I am trying to launch the code of C# WPF app from online MSDN article: "[How to: Schedule Work on the User Interface (UI) Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997394%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" in Visual Studio 2010, Windows XP SP3, .NET4.0

The only differences I've made:

1. changed the namespace from `wpfApplication1` to 
   `WpfApplication1` (since it is in contradiction with article's *"1. In
   Visual Studio, create a WPF application project and name it."*
2. substituted the line

   ```
   string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\", "*.jpg");
   ```

   with

   ```
   string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Documents\My Pictures\Sample Pictures\", "*.jpg");
   ```

   (according to my Windows XP machine's configuration)

But after pressing the button, the app breaks <s>with exception:</s>

> A Task's exception(s) were not observed either by Waiting on the Task
>   or accessing its Exception property. As a result, the unobserved
>   exception was rethrown by the finalizer thread

The code compiles without errors but the line:

```
Matrix m = PresentationSource.FromVisual(Application.Current.MainWindow)
```

has Intellisense with wavy underline showing the popup warning:

> "Possible 'System.NullRederenceException'"

[image: Possible 'System.NullRederenceException']

My VS2010 solution (attempting to reproduce this article) can be downloaded from:
http://wikisend.com/download/404394/msdnHow2ScheduleWorkOnTheUI.rar

What's wrong with this code?
And how to correct it?

**Update:**
The question is not how to observe exception messages but how to launch the MSDN sample code (by a beginner' like me)

I'd prefer asking exception-specific questions separately

**Update2:**
Errata:
Sorry...
The application doesn't break as I wrote before.

I inserted `MessageBox.Show("Finished");` at the end of `button1_Click()` button click event handler.

Upon first click on the button the MessageBox with "Finished!" shows up.
Upon 2nd click it Messagebox again is shown and but app also throws the mentioned above exception.

[image: After 1st click]

And having passed through exception messages and tasks results, I cannot figure out what is wrong!
I'd still like to stress that I am interested in the working sample of article's topic and will post my questions on debugging separately in other question(s)!

Is it reproducible by others?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't see how your title helped that. On the "expressions in tag filters", ask about that on [meta]. It sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: Just to provide a data point, the email notifications I get from StackExchange have a couple of mechanisms to tell me about the area. 1) I name the filter appropriately (and keep multiple filters) so the Subject says "New questions in TPL and async filter for Mar 30 - Stack Exchange" 2) the question's tags are in the body of the email - for this question it included "Tagged: c# .net wpf c#-4.0 task-parallel-library".  Thanks!

Comment: @Fulproof Without you doing the debug legwork and getting us a proper exception, we cannot help you get the sample working. You seem to misunderstand what SO can do. We can help enable you to solve your own problems, not provide you with a magical working example....

Comment: @Justin Pihony, should I understand your comment that he problems I described here aren't reproducible? This is NOT my own problem, it is the code sample from documentation and the only one in the area of TPL Scheduling in WPF!

Comment: @Fulproof Your example code worked for me. I just had to change the Drive in the path from D: to C:.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have an exception that is occurring inside of your task. The message is pretty self-explanatory, but I guess only if you know about exception handling in the TPL. So, to further elaborate on your exact error:

When an exception is thrown from inside of a task, it must be "observed" in 3 different ways:

1. Check the task's `Exception` property
2. Attempt to read the task's `Result` property (Causing any stored exceptions to be thrown)
3. Attach an event handler to the `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException`

If it is not observed in any of the above ways, then the exception will finally be thrown when the garbage collector tries to finalize the task. This is the reason for the exact message you are getting. However, for the deeper, original exception you will need to do one of the 3 above steps and review the actual exception

[Here is an MSDN on exception handling in the TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also, as an FYI, it seems that [this unobserved exception may not HAVE to be handled, but I havent personally dug in](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/clr/thread/a95e7a9c-8b3c-47e6-946e-287531e1a0db/). Even still, it would be better to handle these as you would any code. So, this change should not change how you write your code.

Comment: As your link mentions, in .NET 4.5 unobserved Task exceptions won't throw in the finalizer, but the guidance would still be to have explicit handling for Task exceptions.

Comment: Agreed, and I meant to say that. Will add that now :)

Comment: Thanks! Just to note that my link points to .NET 4.0 article and my question is tagged with "C#-4.0" (I failed to find ".NET-4.0" tag) and I explicitly mentioned ".NET 4.0" in question. And, as beginner, I'd like to dumb launch the code on TPL (scheduling) in WPF (the only one, I could find in MSDN) and ask questions on exception learning experience separately. First to launch and then to deep into code and articles about it. If I cannot launch code then I just skip the resource and search for the one the code from which I can run in order to start diving into the topic

Comment: First, that is why I answered how I did, but did want to let you know of the change made in 4.5. Second, the point I was making is that we cannot help you solve the problem at its root given the code you have provided (sorry, but I am not about to go and upload and open a random rar). But, we can help guide you to solving it on your own. Take the opportunity to learn through debugging the exception. I would argue that is better than copying and pasting some code and expecting it to work. You dont learn as well as doing it yourself.

Comment: @Justin Pihony, there is no need to "upload and open a random rar" which I provided for convenience (in order to save the rime of others only). The question is about the code from MSDN article. Should I understand that 1)you are answering a question without looking into it or 2)you looked and the MSDN sample rums without the problems?